# Does glassfish support proxy protocol headers?

Tags: proxy, glassfish, glassfish-4

Does glassfish support proxy protocol headers?

If so, how do I enable them?

I'm using glassfish 4.1 b13 pre-release.

I have not been able to find any documentation anywhere that states either:

- how to enable proxy protocol header support in glassfish

or

- that glassfish does not support proxy protocol headers

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by proxy protocol headers? Do you just want to connect to a proxy in front if GlassFish?

Comment: @unwichtich A tcp header that contains the ip address of the client instead of any proxy in front of the GlassFish server.

http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol/